# QnAmaker: Trigger Actions for bot training

Tags: azure, triggers, bots

Is it possible to set up a trigger in QnAmaker such that after a new question is added, a certain number of people get notification by email?

To give a background, we have a chatbot on our website where visitors can ask questions, we also log every question and then ask the visitors for their email address if they didn't get a satisfactory answer.

The plan is to send them an email once the bot has been trained with their question. This means we need a trigger from qnamaker to initiate once that question has been added and send the visitor an email.

This is what we plan on doing, but, if anyone can suggest a better way to do it or how to achieve what we want, I am open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send emails to your user after your QnA maker has been trained successfully, you can just use [Get Operation Details API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/operations_getoperationdetails) to monitor the training status, when the `operationState` value turns to `Succeeded`, you can implement your own logic to send emails to your user.

You can get the specific Operation Details API URL in response header:`location` after you call [Update Knowledgebase API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da7600) or get `operationId` in response body：
[image]

Use this URL to get the training status:
[image]

QnA maker portal also use this logic when you click "Save and train" button.

Btw,on Azure, you can use [SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email) service to send emails.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I'll try it out.

Comment: @xyLuz, waiting for your result :)

Comment: Thanks, we have decided to try out dialogflow instead, it seems to have more features and easier integration. Although, I am still not sure if it solves my initial issue.

Comment: @xyLuz,thanks for this update. So could you please lick the mark beside the answer to  accept it so that it could be helpful for others who have similar questions and close this question? Of course if you could share your own way later and accept it that could be great : )